# How can I find the location of the tcsh shell script I'm executing?

Tags: path, shell, directory, tcsh

Say I put an executable tcsh file in  /path/to/my_script.csh

and my current directory is anywhere, for example I'm in /path

So I type to/my_script.csh

I want to have a line in my_script.csh that will return "/path/to/my_script.csh" - like ruby's

```
__FILE__
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In c shell, try like this:

```
set rootdir = `dirname $0`
set abs_rootdir = `cd $rootdir && pwd`
echo $abs_rootdir
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I do this in my #!/bin/csh script, and run it with a relative path (./myscript.csh), it always returns my home directory. Does not matter where I put this script. `dirname $0` is '.' and `pwd` returns my $HOME

Comment: @mdiehl13 The problem you described doesn't happen to me. Do you still see the same issue? You may need check your .cshrc file and see if there are any special configurations related to directory path setting.

Comment: @euccas No, strange (and good). I don't see this behavior anymore

Answer (score 6):

If you want to ensure the same result (full path and script name) try something like this:

```
...
rootdir=`/bin/dirname $0`       # may be relative path
rootdir=`cd $rootdir && pwd`    # ensure absolute path
zero=$rootdir/`/bin/basename $0`
echo $zero
...
```

Then you can call it as foo.sh, ./foo.sh, some/lower/dir/foo.sh and still get the same result no matter how it is called.

Comment: Wrong shell -_-

Answer (score 6):

If you want an absolute path then this should help you out:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f 
set called=($_)

if ( "$called" != "" ) then  ### called by source 
   echo "branch 1"
   set script_fn=`readlink -f $called[2]`
else                         ### called by direct execution of the script
   echo "branch 2"
   set script_fn=`readlink -f $0`
endif

echo "A:$0"
echo "B:$called"
set script_dir=`dirname $script_fn`

echo "script file name=$script_fn"
echo "script dir=$script_dir"
```

Source: http://tipsarea.com/2013/04/11/how-to-get-the-script-path-name-in-cshtcsh/

Comment: Thanks for saving me any more frustration on how to differentiate between the source and a calling script

Comment: This gives the correct result if sourced manually but not if sourced by another script. Is there a way, where it works in this case as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/tcsh
echo "I am $0."
```

Comment: This gives the path from the current directory to the script, not the absolute path.